# clipboardjs does not work when assigning class with space

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, clipboard.js

I have setup clipboardjs successfully. Now  I am adding a framework to it for design purpose.

It is all working fine only when I add a new class to the button called "small button" than it will not work anymore. Before I used a button it will work very well.

I think there is an simple answer but I think I have the wrong look on the issue.

This is the not working example:

```js
< script >
  var clipboard = new Clipboard('.small button');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
}); < /script>
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <label>E-Mail Code:</label>
  <p>
    <textarea id="emailcode">
      <?=$image;?>
    </textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="small button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#emailcode">
      Copy to clipboard
    </button>
  </p>
  <label>Digistore24 Code:</label>
  <p>
    <textarea id="ds24code">
      <?=$ds24;?>
    </textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="small button" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#ds24code">
      Copy to clipboard
    </button>
  </p>
</div>
```

This is the working example:

```js
< script >
  var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
}); < /script>
```

```html
<div class="result">
  <label>E-Mail Code:</label>
  <p>
    <textarea id="emailcode">
      <?=$image;?>
    </textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#emailcode">
      Copy to clipboard
    </button>
  </p>
  <label>Digistore24 Code:</label>
  <p>
    <textarea id="ds24code">
      <?=$ds24;?>
    </textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <button class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#ds24code">
      Copy to clipboard
    </button>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what the issue is.  Saying "not working" is not helpful - copy the error message(s) into the question or at least describe the symptoms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a double class to your button as posted down below. First you post "btn" and then with a space the relevant css from the framework.

```
<button class="btn small button" data-clipboard-action="copy" 
data-clipboard-target="#ds24code">
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed when initializing the clipboard library is a CSS selector, so the code you have

```
new Clipboard('.small button')
```

will find `button` tags within tags of `small` class. What you want is probably

```
new Clipboard('.small.button')
```

which will find tags having both `small` and `button` classes.